# is there an effective attack against rsa by knowing the coefficient $u$ of the private key?

Tags: rsa, attack

consider that an attacker has the public key $(n, e)$, where $n$ is $1024$ bits long, the $32$ largest bits of $p$ (where $n = p \cdot q$), as well as $u = p^{-1} \pmod q$. Is there an attack that would allow this attacker to perform an attack on rsa and therefore be able to decrypt a message or retrieve the private key $(n, d)$?

Comment: Could you add an explanation why your attacker knows exactly this information?

Comment: this is in the case where the attacker has retrieved this information from pieces of PEM or DER key pair files mainly